# The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed with ClaimsTransformer

Tags: asp.net-core

We have an ASP.NET core 3.1 app and we are getting this error.This is the line that starts off the error:

System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, out bool someFailed)
It was working a few months ago.but not now...
im using windows authotification and claimsTransformer to add Roles...

public Task TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{

```
        var ci = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
        var test = ci.Name.Split('\\');
        string login = test[1];

        var uerConnected = _commissionnementService.GetAllUserRole().Where(x => x.WindowsLogin == login).FirstOrDefault();
        if(uerConnected != null)
        {
            var c = new Claim(ci.RoleClaimType, uerConnected.Role);
            ci.AddClaim(c);
        }
        
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
```

can you tell me what's going on? please...

Comment: Please share the configuration you set for windows authentication and the complete code of Claims Transformation, so that we can reproduce and troubleshoot the issue better.